# Facebook Messenger Bot - not working public

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I created a facebook page and facebook messenger bot.  I was all geeked when the bot worked as designed under my profile.  But when i asked friends to test it out.  My page name would not appear in the messenger.  The page will come up in a search.  Then if they click send a message, and ask the bot a question...the bot will not work.

Stumped
1.  why my pageid does not appear as a FB messenger recipient
2.  why does bot not work for users

Answer (score 6):

Once you submitted the bot for review and got pages_messaging permission.
Go to App Review, you will be seeing an option to make the bot public, turn it to Yes and it's done.

Comment: I have the same problem and there is no such permission on submit for review. Does it take time to go public after i turn it on?

Comment: Firstly get you app reviewed, look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/app-review         submit your app for review, once it done you can make your app public.

Comment: but i have to select a permission from the checkboxes on the left to be able to submit for review. There is no option for messenger...

Comment: Is your app working fine for administrator and test user ?

Comment: Thanks, need to make bot public after approval.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your friend to test your bot in development mode even before you apply to go public. You can do these two things...

1. go to your app dashboard in roles and add your friend as testers to the app.
2. Add them as admin to the facebook page linked to the app

Now they will be able to fully interact with the bot in development mode.
Note: The users that you want to test don't have to even be your facebook friends. You can also add them from their facebook id. This is useful if you want a client to test the bot before applying to go public and you don't want them to intrude in your personal facebook life.

Answer (score 2):

It's really simple once you know how to add users who can test your bot, If you want a public user to test your bot maybe your **friend/tester**, you simply need to follow the below steps.

1. Go to your Facebook Developer Panel.
2. Select your bot app.
3. Reach out for the **Roles** tab.
4. Select whether you want to add the person as a
   developer/tester/admin. Go for the tester option if unsure.
5. You can select the name/username/fbid of the person you want to
   add.
6. Add the person and ask him to accept the request and you are good
   to go.

Answer (score 1):

When your app is in [Development Mode](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/managing-development-cycle), plugin and API functionality will only work for admins, developers and testers of the app. After your app is approved and public, it will work for the general public.

Answer (score 0):

To make your bot public. Submit it for review.
Just go to the submit tab on the right just below dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The fix is - in your messenger settings, you will have to request for atleast one permission (i.e. pages_messaging) to allow your bot to send and receive messages. After selecting "Add to submission", you will have to complete the pre-requisites for submission and wait for response from Facebook.

For more details:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/app-review